# Programming include inequality (R)

Tags: r, inequality

These is what i did, given h = 5 and get the value of ARL=2.5.

```
C=[1,5,8,9,7,8,1,2,5,5]
h=5
n=10
ooc=C>h
lenOOC = sum(ooc)
lenOOC
>4
p=lenOOC/n
p
>0.4
ARL=1/p
ARL
>2.5
```

But now i need is given the value of ARL and compute the value of h=?
for example, with same data set of C.

```
ARL=1.428571
n=10
lenOOC=n/ARL
lenOOC
>7...
```

and how to proceed to get the value of h? given `ooc=C>h`.

Hope you all can understand what im trying to ask..
Thanks for helping..=]]

Comment: ohh ya.. thank you..

Comment: Notice from your original example that `lenOOC = sum(ooc)` _must_ be an integer 1,2,3,...10.  Since you are getting `lenOOC = 0.027` you are starting with an impossible value of ARL.

Comment: lhow about if I change the value of ARL to ARL=1.428571?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lenOOC=n/ARL` You want h so that  `lenOOC = sum(C>h)`. that is you want to find a number `h` so that `lenOOC` of the numbers are strictly bigger than `h`.  That is the same as `n - lenOOC` are less than or equal to `h`  so you want the `n - lenOOC` biggest number. Just sort the numbers in C and pick the  `n - lenOOC` biggest number.

```
C=c(1,5,8,9,7,8,1,2,5,5)
ARL=1.428571
n=10
lenOOC=n/ARL
sort(C)[n - round(lenOOC)]
[1] 2
```

So h = 2.

But notice that this will not work for all values of ARL.  What if we tried ARL = 10/9 = 1.1111111
This would give

```
ARL=1.111111
lenOOC=n/ARL
sort(C)[n - round(lenOOC)]
[1] 1
```

But h=1 would actually give ARL = 1.25   **No number** will give ARL=1.111111. The above method only works for possible values of ARL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patient and solution. Help me. =]]